# No Network Connection in spite of Internet Connection

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

Setup a server with Ubuntu 16.04. Noob w/ most actions via GUI.

Installed a few packages like GUFW, TeamViewer, OpenJDK 8, Unifi Controller, etc. via xTerm. Scratched my head when seeing "Go Online to check for updates" when viewing the Updates tab of Ubuntu Software.

Nonetheless, there is an internet connection obviously as i'm able to download software, browse the internet via firefox, connect remotely via TeamViewer on LAN, etc.

When clicking on the Networking icon, i see "Networking Enabled". Connection Information shows "Error Displaying Connection Information: No valid active connections found!". I created a new one with IPv4 (my case) and Automatic DHCP for Method. Saved. Still nothing. 
So the server has internet with no apparent ethernet connection.

```
ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: p9p1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fc:aa:14:22:e8:8b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.53/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global p9p1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::feaa:14ff:fe22:e88b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 p9p1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 p9p1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 p9p1

Kernel IPv6 routing table
Destination                    Next Hop                   Flag Met Ref Use If
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 0     0 p9p1
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1   465 lo
::1/128                        ::                         Un   0   7   160 lo
fe80::feaa:14ff:fe22:e88b/128  ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 6    50 p9p1
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1   465 lo
```

the last command returns nothing

Comment: Add output of  `ip addr`, `route -n4`,  `route -n6` and `env | grep -i proxy`  (eventually mask  public IP addresses, just in case)

Comment: i've updated my post with the info.

Comment: Okay, that looks like a pretty standard configuration.  Private network on `192.168.1/24` with gateway on `192.168.1.1`.  Everything is IPv4, and IPv6 is not truly in use (I wanted to be sure it wasn't an IPv6-only connection. They are rare, but they exist).  There seems to be a Bonjour Network, but that's also irrelevant.

Basically, everything looks totally in order.  It might just be the graphical interface that has problems.  Have you tried restarting network manager?  (Beware if you do this on a server which you can only access over network) ` sudo service network-manager restart`.

Comment: Thanks jawtheshark. unfortunately restarting the service did nothing useful for the situation.

Comment: I don't really know what is going on.  I wouldn't worry too much, since it's a server and you're unlikely to actually need network manager.  Anyway, can you add the output of  `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`?